# program running with showing progress bar in netbean but result does not come

Tags: java, arrays

I am defining an array to be a 121 array if all its elements are either 1 or 2 and it begins with one or more 1s followed by one or more 2s and end with same number of 1s that it begins with.

However i am not getting result while I was running my program.If program was ok I must get result 1 for given array {1,1,2,2,2,1,1}.

please help me.

```
 public class OneTwoOne {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(OneTwoOne.is121Array(new int[]{1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1}));
}

public static int is121Array(int[] a) {

    int i, t1 = 0, t2 = 0, te = 0, tb = 0, tc = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {//checking 1's and 2's in an array

        if (a[i] == 1) {

            t1 = 1;
        }
        if (a[i] == 2) {
            t2 = 2;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {//counting number of 1's at begining of array

        while (a[i] == 1) {

            tb++;
        }
        break;
    }

    for (i = a.length; i >= 0; i--) {//counting number of 1's at end of array

        while (a[i] == 1) {
            te++;
        }
        break;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {//counting total number of 1's in an array

        if (a[i] == 1) {
            tc++;
        }
    }

    if (t1 > 0 && t2 > 0 && t1 == t2 && te + tb == tc) {
        //1's and 2's must be greater thna 0 and begining 1's and end 1's must be equal 
        //their sum is equal to total 1's in an array
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Your best bet is to step through it in the debugger so you understand what's going on, and what's going wrong.

Comment: You trap in infinite loops for two `while` loops, you must change them to `if`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using while loop instead of "if" clause, also the for loop limit is also unnecessarily long enough which is causing wrong result. I have made some changes in your method:

```
   /* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

//StackOverflow question. 
//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32045039/array-elements-beginning-and-ending-with-1s-by-equal-number-at-both-end-and-oth/32045312#32045312


/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class OneTwoOne {

    static  int i, t1 = 0, t2 = 0, te = 0, tb = 0, tc = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int a [] = new int[]{1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1};
        int retunValue = OneTwoOne.is121Array(a);
        System.out.println("Number of 1s in starting ::"+te +"\n Number of 1s in the end ::"+ tb +"");
        System.out.println("Return value :: "+retunValue );


}

public static int is121Array(int[] a) {
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {//checking 1's and 2's in an array

        if (a[i] == 1) {

            t1 = 1;
        }
        if (a[i] == 2) {
            t2 = 2;
        }
    }
    int length = a.length;
    for (i = 0; i < length/2; i++) {//counting number of 1's at begining of array

        if (a[i] == 1) {

            tb++;
        }

    }

    for (i = a.length-1; i >= length/2; i--) {//counting number of 1's at end of array

        if (a[i] == 1) {
            te++;
        }

    }
    if (te == tb)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
}
```

You may run this program [here](https://ideone.com/CGdwcK). You may access the complete code [here](https://gist.github.com/MaheshKapoor/760fe9584ccce06f7d2a).

Comment: thanks for response but result is still 0 instead of 1 in case of array {1,1,2,2,2,1,1}    @Mahesh kapoor

Comment: Could you please check the working program https://ideone.com/CGdwcK    - let me know if you need more changes according to your requirement.

Comment: I have updated my answer with new code. You may try now.